# Ping `hostname` stuck about 5 seconds on macOS Sierra

Tags: network, dns

I will describe this problem details in shell interaction records:

```
$ host `hostname`
Host myhost.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ cat /etc/hosts | grep 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 localhost myhost.local

$ ping `hostname` # stuck about 5 seconds (maybe a DNS query timeout)
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
```

Comment: This problem did have some side effects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971955/slow-logback-start-up-times

Comment: do you get the same behaviour when you do `ping localhost`

Comment: @Deesbek ping localhost has no delay on my machine

Comment: interesting. Any reason why you are running `hostname`. I get the exact same output to all the same commands as you or at least could do had I set my hostname to myhost.local.  I would try setting your domain to a resolvable domain.  In any case I cannot replicate your delay.